# how to get any specific date of current year

Tags: java, date

Hi I was wondering if there was any way using Jav's Date class or and Joda Time classes to get any specific day of this year.  For example if I want the date `12/31/2013`. The reason why this is a problem is because I am giving a string representation of someone's birthday lets say `"12311991"` `"MMddyyyy"` and I want to convert this to be a Date which has `month 12 day 31 and year 2013`.

Can anyone help me on this?

I am using the DateMidnight Joda time class and I parse the string into a date using Simple Formatter but I was wondering if there was any way to set the year to be a specific year.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to implement using [JodaTime](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/quickstart.html) you can do as below. Format using  [DateTimeFormatter](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html) to get `DateTime` and then with [DateTime#withYear(int)](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/DateTime.html#withYear%28int%29) method, year can be changed.

```
String dob = "12311991";
DateTimeFormatter fmt = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("MMddyyyy");
DateTime dt = fmt.parseDateTime(dob).withYear(2013);
System.out.println(dt);
```

Answer (score 5):

Start by converting the `String` to a `Date`...

```
String dateString = "12311991";
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MMddyyyy");

Date date = sdf.parse(dateString);
```

Which results in ....

```
Tue Dec 31 00:00:00 EST 1991
```

Next, use `Calendar` to modify the `year`

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.setTime(date);
cal.set(Calendar.YEAR, 2013);
date = cal.getTime();
```

Which results in...

```
Tue Dec 31 00:00:00 EST 2013
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using Calendar

```
set(int year,
   int month,
   int date)
```

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#set(int, int, int)

Answer (score 1):

Just use SimpleDateFormat ([**click me**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) to see all format patterns).

```
String string = "12/31/2013";
Date date = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/mm/yyyy", Locale.ENGLISH).parse(string);
System.out.println(date);
```

Answer (score 0):

## java.time

The other answers are outdated. The old date-time classes, as well as Joda-Time, have been supplanted by the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework built into Java 8 and later.

The [`LocalDate`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html) class truly represents a date-only value without time-of-day and without time zone (lacking in the original date-time classes).

```
String input = "12311991";
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.forPattern("MMddyyyy");
LocalDate localDate = LocalDate.parse( input , formatter ); // 1991-12-31
LocalDate differentYear = localDate.withYear( 2013 );  // 2013-12-31
```